# Fallback for loading content from external source with $.get()

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

Hi I need some help with a simple ajax request function. It actually works fine, but I need to implement a fallback in case the files (.txt) can't be loaded from the main source, I then want to load them from a fallback Dropbox folder..

User clickes on element with id="filename", url hash gets updated with #filename, I then fetch the hash and make a request to load the file from an external source like somedomain.com/folder/filename.txt
(It also works without the click event just by adding the hash to the actual url because I trigger .hashchange on load)

Here's my code:

```
// get ID from clicked element

$(".info").click(function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("id");
        event.preventDefault();
});

// bind to hashchange (to be able to load request from URL hash)

$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {

        // Get hash and store in variable
        var myclass;
        $myclass = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        // construct file url from source path + filename
        $source = 'http://www.somedomain.de/folder/' + $myclass + '.txt';

        // alternative source as fallback
        $source_alt = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/someDropboxFolder/' + $myclass + '.txt';

        // load contents from .txt file and replace html of "#container"
        $.get($source, function(data) {$("#container").html(data);}, 'text');
        // --> IF THIS FAILS I WANT TO MAKE A CALL TO LOAD FROM ALTERNATIVE SOURCE (source_alt)

});   

$(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

I tried to add .fail() but this did not work to the request but this did not work with  ".fail() is not a function"...

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will catch it in error and load data from another resource.

```js
var failed_resource = false;
var jqxhr = $.get( "example.php", function() {
      alert( "success" );
    })
      .done(function() {
        alert( "second success" );
      })
      .fail(function() {
         failed_resource = true; 
        alert( "error loading resource. Load data from another resource.." );
      })
      .always(function() {
        alert( "finished request." );
        if(failed_resource == true) {
          loadDataFromAnotherRes();
          }
      });
function loadDataFromAnotherRes() {
  // your code here
  alert('Loading data from another resource..');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answers, after trying this out and still getting ".done() is not a function, I found out that the site I'm working on is on jquery 1.4.2 I'mm not a big fan of overwriting jquery versions and I can't change the whole setup because it's a clients website.
I guess I'll have to live without the fallback.

Comment: I accept this answer anyways because I just tested with jquery 1.8.3 and there it works fine. If anybody can provide a solution which is before jq 1.5 I'll give extra thumbs but I know it's not worth the effort. really don't understand why people do not update their stuff. sigh

Answer (score 1):

Use full syntax:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: // your URL,
    data: // your data if needed,
    success: function (result) { ... }, // your action on success
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { ... } // your action on error
});
```

You may check which error took place during your request, and then modify your logics according to it